# akka-http complex json convert

Tags: json, akka

I want to implement a restful http service using akka http.
POST method receive  json params and do sth.

```
{
    "user": {
        "userid": 123,
        "reqid": "abcdef",
        "username": "张三"
    },
    "article": {
        "atype": 1,
        "fromdate": "2017-06-27"
    },
    "tags": {
        "fixtags": [
            { "t":"t1", "w": 30 },
            { "t":"t2", "w": 20 },
            { "t":"t3", "w": 10 },
            { "t":"t4", "w": 50 }
        ],
        "atags": [
            { "t":"t5", "w": 30 },
            { "t":"t6", "w": 20 }
        ]
    }
}
```

case class

```
case class Article(atype: Int, fromdate: String)
case class Tag(t: String, w: Double)
case class FixTags(fixtags: List[Tag])
case class ATags(atags: List[Tag])
//case class Tags( fixtags: List[Map[String, Float]], atags: List[Map[String, Float]] )
case class Tags(fixtags: FixTags, atags: ATags)

case class AUserInfo(user: User, article: Article, tags: Tags)
implicit val userFormat1 = jsonFormat3( User )
implicit val artFormat1 = jsonFormat2( Article )
implicit val tagFormat1 = jsonFormat2( Tag )
implicit val ftagFormat1 = jsonFormat1( FixTags )
implicit val atagFormat1 = jsonFormat1( ATags )
implicit val tagsFormat1 = jsonFormat2( Tags )

implicit val userFormat = jsonFormat3( AUserInfo )
```

route:

```
path( "rcmd" / LongNumber ) {
            userid =>
                post {


                    entity( as[AUserInfo] ) { userinfo =>do sth}
```

as[AUserInfo] will report error:

> The request content was malformed:
>       Object expected in field 'fixtags'%

or:

> could not find implicit value for parameter um: 
>       akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.Unmarshaller

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what the error:
because my json string format not fit my case class.
I change the case class to below and fix that error:

```
//case class FixTags(fixtags: List[Tag])
//case class ATags(atags: List[Tag])

case class Tags(fixtags: List[Tag], atags: List[Tag])
```